# A closed form for $T_N = 1 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N-2}{(N-1-k)T_k}$?

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

I've narrowed down a problem I am working on to the following recurrence:

$$\begin{align*}
T_0 &= T_1 = 1\\
T_N &= 1 + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2}{(N-1-k)T_k}
\end{align*}$$

I'm stuck on how to close it up, or at least make it linear or $O(n\log n)$.  Any clues as to what technique I can use to make the sum into a closed form?

Comment: Generating functions should work. See, for example, Wilf (http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html).

Comment: Please avoid titles that are entirely in $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, consider the differences between consecutive values:  We have $$\begin{align*}T_{N+1}-T_N &= \left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}(N-k)T_k\right)-\left(\sum_{k=0}^{N-2}(N-1-k)T_k\right) \\
&= \bigl(N-(N-1)\bigr)T_{N-1} + \sum_{k=0}^{N-2}\biggl((N-k)-(N-1-k)\biggr)T_k \\
&= T_{N-1}+\sum_{k=0}^{N-2}T_k \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}T_k\end{align*}$$
Or in other words $T_{N+1} = \sum_{k=0}^N T_k$.  Can you figure out the rest from there?

(Incidentally, one way of arriving at a good closed-form for your recurrence, or at least starting a guess, is just to start plugging in values!  Quick calculation shows that $T_2=1+1\cdot T_0 = 2$, $T_3 = 1+2\cdot T_0 + 1\cdot T_1 = 4$, and $T_4 = 1+3\cdot T_0+2\cdot T_1+1\cdot T_2 = 8$, and that should lead pretty easily to a hypothesis about $T_N$; from there it's just a matter of proving your guess.)

Comment: I made a mistake sorry: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177856/t-n1-t-n-sum-k-1nt-k-1t-n-k-implies-oecd-a001006-how-to