# Finding Possible number of structures by forming loops of different sizes in N clockwise arranged points

Tags: combinatorics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count Exclusive Partitionings of Points in Circle, Closing Double Recurrence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/178043/count-exclusive-partitionings-of-points-in-circle-closing-double-recurrence)

We have **N** fixed points in a circle,numbered 1 to **N** in clockwise order.
We can form closed loop of 2 points or 3 points upto **N** points (let say it size of loop) i.e. by taking any three points, we can form a triangle or by taking two points, a line can be formed, or by 4 points a square can be formed.

A structure is one, which have unique organised loops.

- It may have one or more than one closed loops.
- One structure can have loops of different size.
- No two loops should cross each other.
- One point can't share more than one loop in a structure.

For Example, say **N**=8

Possible structures are:

- loop (1,2,3) if only occurs, it will be one structure.
- loop (2,3,4) if only occurs, it will be other structure.
- loop (1,2,3) and loop (6,7,8) will be other structure.
- loop (2,4,5,6) loop (7,8) will also be an structure.

loop (1,2,4,5) and loop (3,6,8) **can't** form structure as both will cross each other.

**So for N, how many structures are possible?**

Comment: Loops are of straight edges, so consider it polygon (including straight line) rather than a curved loop

Comment: Is loop (7,8,1,2) allowed? How about loop (1,4,5)?  And can you have individual points not in a loop (or loops of 1 point)?

Comment: @Henry: I would take the first example, $(1,2,3)$ for $N=8$, to mean that the answer to your second question is "yes". Regarding your first question, how is $(1,4,5)$ different from the allowed loop $(2,4,5,6)$?

Comment: @joriki Thanks man, Its exactly what I was looking for.